# Spring - cannot find bean by nested generic interface type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a problem with generic beans in Spring / Kotlin.

I have these interfaces:

```kotlin
interface Query<T>

interface QueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult : Any> where TQuery : Query<TResult> {
    fun execute(query: TQuery): TResult
}
```

and dispatcher:

```kotlin
class InMemoryQueryDispatcher(
    private val applicationContext: GenericWebApplicationContext
) : QueryDispatcher() {
    override fun <TQuery : Query<TResult>, TResult : Any> dispatch(query: TQuery, queryType: KClass<TQuery>, resultType: KClass<TResult>): TResult {
        val beanFactory = applicationContext.beanFactory

        val resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(QueryHandler::class.java, queryType.java, resultType.java)
        val beans = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(resolvableType)

        val handler = beanFactory.getBean<QueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>(beans.first())
        ...
    }
}
```

When I have handler like this:

```kotlin
class GetUserHandler() : QueryHandler<GetUser, UserDto> { ... }
```

everything works well.

But when I specify another generic for return type:

```kotlin
class GetUsersHandler() : QueryHandler<GetUsers, List<UserDto>> { ... }
```

Spring cannot find my handler.

`ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(...)` produces ResolvableType `QueryHandler<GetUsers, List<?>>` and it tries to match `QueryHandler<GetUsers, List<UserDto>>` - shouldn't that wildcard match it?

I tried to debug Spring's code. It matches `QueryHandler`, then `GetUser`, then `List` and it fails on matching `?` with `UserDto`.

This part of `ResolvableType.java` fails ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.java#L303)):

```java
if (typeBounds != null) {
    return (ourBounds != null && ourBounds.isSameKind(typeBounds) &&
            ourBounds.isAssignableFrom(typeBounds.getBounds()));
}
```

I was also thinking of passing multiple types to `forClassWithGenerics()`, but this doesn't work either, because my `QueryHandler` has only 2 "top level" types and `forClassWithGenerics()` won't accept third nested type.

Is there any way to make this working?

Thank you in advance!